# Process substitution not working for input files with iconv

Tags: bash, iconv

Running this in bash.

As I read the man page for iconv it accepts multiple input files hence

The cat in

```
iconv --from-code ISO_8859-1 --to-code UTF8 <( cat <(sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' actors.list)  <(sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' actresses.list)  <(sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' directors.list))
```

should not be necessary but if I don't have it there it only data from the actors.list file appears in the output.

Comment: Do you get an error from iconv if you don't have that wrapping cat substitution?

Comment: did you look at how this is processed by setting the shell debug/trace with `set -vx` (`set +vx` to turn it off). Good luck.

Comment: @Etan I did not observe any error but it only processes the first file.

Comment: In a quick test here I got the first files contents and then `iconv: error while reading the input: Bad address`. Which sounds like an issue with `iconv` to me (iconv 2.5).

Comment: You mean this thing that I didn't pay attention to. iconv: error while reading the input: Bad address. Yes  I got it but didn't note it. So what now. Notify the author?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly a bug in the `iconv` which is distributed with `glibc`. The bug is triggered by providing more than one non-mmapable command line input.

The simplest workaround is to provide a single input by putting the invocations of `sed` into a single command substitution:

```
iconv --from-code ISO_8859-1 --to-code UTF8 \
      <(sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' actors.list
        sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' actresses.list
        sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' directors.list)
```

In this particular case, you could just use one `sed` command:

```
iconv --from-code ISO_8859-1 --to-code UTF8 \
      <(sed  '/^KEYWORD INTERFACE/,$d' \
             actors.list actresses.list directors.list)
```

Of course, you could also insert a redundant `cat` as in the OP.

---

Bug reported to glibc as https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17703